# The reason why Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an expandable / collapse table view.

I use Storyboard. **And I also checked storyboard.**

There is no problem with building.

But it doesn't work on emulators.

```
import UIKit

class NoticeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var noticeTableView: UITableView!
    
    var imageArr = ["cm_contents_01", "cm_contents_02", "cm_contents_03"]
    var nameArr = ["Notice 1", "Notice 2", "Notice 3"]
    
    var selectedIndex = -1
    var isCollapce = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        noticeTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 3000
        noticeTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
...
```

There's an error here.

```
noticeTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 3000
```

And Storyboard connection.

[image]

When it was made separately, it was executed well, but it is combined with other projects, so there is an error.

```
Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

Please tell me why there is an error.

Comment: How are you presenting `NoticeViewController`?

Comment: I use Navigation controller and Side Menu.

Comment: Can you show the code that presents `NoticeViewController`?

Comment: You are probably not creating the view controller from the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making your own instance of `NoticeViewController`:

```
private let noticeController = NoticeViewController()
```

But you are using Storyboard too! Instead of doing that, you need to get to get properly your `NoticeViewController` from your Storyboard, like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MenuControllerDelegate {
    private var sideMenu: SideMenuNavigationController?
    
    private var noticeController: NoticeViewController?

....

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    self.noticeController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourControllerId"
}
```

and then from there, you'll have a proper instance of your `NoticeViewController`. The crash you are experiencing literally means the `tableView` object is missing (nil).